# PHP Get request with object inside query

Tags: php, facebook, get, facebook-insights

following the facebook documentation to get the page insights, when i use the same query in the graph api explorer i get results, but the query in my php is throwing an error saying

"Argument 1 passed to Facebook\FacebookRequest::__construct() must be an instance of Facebook\FacebookSession, null given, called in /Library/WebServer/Documents/fbLogin/app/helper/FacebookHelper.php on line 57 and defined"

This is my **controller**

```
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;


class FacebookHelper
{   
  public function getInsights($pageid){
        $request = new FacebookRequest($this->session, 'GET', '/{pageid}/insights');
        $response = $request->execute();
        return $response->getGraphObject();
    }
}
```

if i var_dump($pageid) it shows me the pageid, so thats not the issue. I feel i am making a mistake in GET query.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of things your `$this->session` is null. Try dumping it to check that it's value is set correctly.

It should be an instance of `Facebook\FacebookSession`

Comment: yes its displaying null .. have no idea why, has been working fine for every other function

Comment: You need to figure out why this is happening as that is your problem. Are you able to post the entire `FacebookHelper` class?

Comment: figured it out, while changing views the session access token was getting reset. Just passing it through along with my route and calling a new token before making the FacebookRequest.